# Why does my code only allow me to drag and drop the uppermost duplicate item in a listview box

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have some code (shown below) for a pc running c# within a Windows Forms Application using Microsoft Visual Studio.

I'm trying to implement user reordering of the text contents of a listview window using DragDrop and MouseDown instructions.

The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to re-order an item which has an exact duplicate (or duplicates) within the same listview window, whichever one I click to drag to move to a new position within the same list, the one that's moved is always the topmost one.

So, for instance, I could have one duplicate at the very bottom and one at the very top of the list and if I click and drag the bottom one and drop near the top, it's always the top duplicate that's moved rather than the one I actually dragged at the bottom. So the top one always seems to take priority.

```
private void Playlist_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int item_index_pickup = Playlist.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);

            if (item_index_pickup >= 0 && item_index_pickup < 
            Playlist.Items.Count)

            {
                Playlist.DoDragDrop(Playlist.SelectedItem, 
                DragDropEffects.Move);

                playlist_reorder = true;
            }
        }

private void Playlist_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            int item_index_drop = Playlist.IndexFromPoint(
            Playlist.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));

            Playlist.Items.Remove(Playlist.SelectedItem);

            if (item_index_drop >= 0 && item_index_drop < 
            Playlist.Items.Count)
            // Check whether item is inserted or added to end of list

            {
                Playlist.Items.Insert(item_index_drop, 
                e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));

                Playlist.ClearSelected();
            }

            else // Add item to the end of the list

            {
                string chosen_file = (string)e.Data.GetData
                (DataFormats.StringFormat);

                Playlist.Items.Add(chosen_file);

                Playlist.ClearSelected();
            }

        }
```

Thanks for your insight and experience.

Martin

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: This is much more broad than you think - Microsoft seems to have a ListView in every platform/technology they support.  Since you didnt indicate the technology (tags), we cant help.

Comment: It is not obvious to me how you could tell that the right one got "moved", given that they are duplicates.  The code does have a basic bug, it doesn't move the selected item, it copies it.  If a real move is intended then you have to Remove/At() the selected item and re-insert it at the target index.

Comment: The way I can tell which got moved when I reorder is that I’m never able to move the bottom most one of the two (or more) duplicate items upwards - so whichever of the duplicate items I drag upwards (which may be separated in the list), the uppermost of the duplicate items is always moved. The uppermost of the duplicates is moved around freely regardless of which one I try to drag around. There is a remove line in the code above: Playlist.Items.Remove(Playlist.SelectedItem);